# How can I setup a app_identity account as an administrator for my google apps domain

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps

I have an appengine application that allows users to register themselves. These users must be able to send e-mail from a google apps domain. To do this, I want the appengine application to use the provisioning API to create new users in the apps domain.

I could of course create a custom administrative account for the apps domain. Then I could use a normal gdata.apps.client.ClientLogin. However, that would also mean that the userid and password are stored in source code or in the application.

Is it possible to tell the apps domain that the appengine's service account (its app_identity account) is an administrator for the apps domain?

If that's not possible, any tips on how I can secure the userid and password in the appengine application?

Hans Then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell what I want is not possible. I'll have to setup a userid and password in my apps account and login using that.

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to use 3 legged oauth for authentication with provisioning api. Here's some docs https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/auth/oauth#Examples

Comment: If I understand these examples correctly, they function in a different use case. In the oauth examples, the oauth libraries forward a request to a login page, where the user can enter his credentials. This will return an access token which the application can then use to access the appropriate user data. I.O.W. the application "borrows" the user's credentials to log in.

In my use case I want the application to authenticate to google apps  on its own. It should be able to create a _new_ apps user, without an authenticated user in the session.

Comment: You obviously can't access the API without authenticating, and the only way to authenticate to the google apps provisioning api is either with client login (ie username and password - this is a bad solution) or with oauth. The provisioning api only supports 3 legged oauth for writing, so you can't seemlessly authenticate without getting the user to accept the access token first. This is probably a good thing, so users know up front what the app is going to be doing with their data. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. As far as I am aware oauth only works with users that already have a google account (or some other account). This is not the case for me. I want users to create new google apps accounts for themselves and inside my appengine application. This means there is no user account to accept the access token. I had hopes I could identify my application using its app_identity, but I cannot add an app_identity as an administrator to the google apps domain (only accounts from  the google apps domain can be added as administrators).

Comment: You would get an admin of the domain to create the token. The token will then allow you to create other accounts in the domain. This obviously doesn't work cross domain (unless they are secondary domains). If you want to actually create google apps domains from scratch, then there is no API for that!